# I am trying to use @Query for my mongoDB repository interface, to query based on a int32 value

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-mongodb

```
package com.tip.report.repositories;

import com.tip.report.models.Score;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface ScoreRepository extends MongoRepository<Score, String> {

    @Query(value = "{ 'sem.id' : ?0 }")
    List<Score> findBySemId(final int semId);

}
```

The above query won't return any result or exceptions.
What should I do if I want to keep the field type as int32 and get result?

Tried Long, int datatypes and no luck.

Given below is the structure of the document.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62ecf36514d8dc7a43080d8a"),
    "testResults" : [
        {
            "test" : "lorem ipsum",
            "testCode" : NumberInt(87),
            "warnings" : [
                "certificate, valid from  2022-07-27 10:10:01"
            ],
            "warningCodes" : [
                NumberInt(6001)
            ]
        },
        {
            "test" : "lorem ipsum dolor sit",
            "testCode" : NumberInt(88),
            "warnings" : [
                "lorem ipsum",
                "lorem ipsum dolor sit",
            ],
            "warningCodes" : [
                NumberInt(6015),
                NumberInt(6019),
                NumberInt(6021)
            ]
        }
    ],
    "sem" : {
        "id" : NumberInt(72),
        "sem_number" : "5"
    },
    "score" : 88.58
}
```